# Finding associated primes of $k[x, y]/(y^2, xy)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm currently working on Vakil, exercise 6.6.T, from the [July 31 2023 version](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGjul3123public.pdf). It asks to show that for $f \in k[x, y]/(y^2, xy)$, $\operatorname{Supp} f$ is the empty set, the origin, or the whole space. This I did fine; the support is empty exactly when $f = 0$, the origin $(x, y)$ when $f = ay$, and the whole space for everything else.

It also asks to find the associated primes of this ring. I assume I'm supposed to use the fact that $\operatorname{Supp} f = V(\operatorname{Ann} f)$, as primary ideals haven't been discussed yet so probably aren't required.

So given associated prime $\mathfrak{p}$ with $\mathfrak{p} = \operatorname{Ann} f$, we have that $\operatorname{Supp} f = V(\operatorname{Ann} f) = V(\mathfrak{p})$, and we can use the trichotomy of the supports established above to find all associated primes. As always, nothing can be associated to $\operatorname{Ann} 0$, as that ideal is the whole ring, so we only have to worry about $\operatorname{Supp} f = (x, y)$ and $\operatorname{Supp} f = \operatorname{Spec} k[x, y]/(y^2, xy)$.

In the first case, $V(\mathfrak{p}) = \operatorname{Supp} f = (x, y)$, meaning $\mathfrak{p} = I(V(\mathfrak{p})) = I\big((x, y)\big) = \sqrt{(x, y)} = (x, y)$. This makes sense, as clearly $(x, y) = \operatorname{Ann} y$.

The last case is what is confusing me. If the support is the whole spectrum, then $V(\mathfrak{p})$ is the whole spectrum, meaning $\mathfrak{p} = I(V(\mathfrak{p})) = I\big(\operatorname{Spec} k[x, y]/(y^2, xy)\big)= \sqrt{0}$, the nilradical. The nilradical is the ideal $\sqrt{(y^2, xy)}$.

This is the point at which I'm stuck. Is there a better (non primary decomposition) way of seeing if there are any more associated primes? The union of associated primes is the set of zero divisors, and every zero divisor in this ring is in $(x, y)$, so I would assume that the last case doesn't yield anything, but I'm struggling to see how to directly show no associated prime can exist there.

Any hints or comments are much appreciated!

Comment: I've added a version and a link to the copy you're working out of and replaced each instance of `$\text{...} \, $` with `$\operatorname{...}$` which produces the correct spacing with less fuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't show that there's no associated prime there because there is one - for noetherian schemes, the generic point of an irreducible component is always an associated point (in more algebraic language, [every minimal prime ideal of a noetherian ring is an associated prime](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30792/a-direct-proof-that-minimal-primes-are-associated)). Specifically, $\sqrt{(0)}=(y)$ which is the annihilator of $x$.

Comment: Thanks; I have no idea how I calculated the nilradical wrong; seems obvious now. In general, is this a good procedure to use when calculating associated primes by hand?

Comment: I'm not sure you were wrong, perhaps you just didn't go all the way to the end. I think the procedure that Vakil outlines here is a pretty solid thing to try at first.